# Spock test: Can when/then block labels be omitted (keeping code formerly separated by labels)? Are the labels syntax sugar?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, syntax, spock

In [Spock testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/), are the `when:` and `then:` [block labels](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_blocks) (labels themselves, not the code/[phases](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_blocks) they separate) strictly necessary?  Or are they technically just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), that can be omitted (while still having/keeping the code lines that would otherwise be separated by the labels)?

**I'm not sure if the stimulus/response phases (respective to when/then) still execute the same, when omitting the labels?**

(I am curious to ask this, for the purpose of possibly saving a few lines of code; that may be relatively trivial, but I appreciate if anyone who can answer would humor me.  I am in a context where there are no non-technical or less-technical users reading or writing Spock tests - I respect other contexts where including labels aids in readability for the other non/less-technical users; that makes sense.)

For example (1), consider the below [feature method](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_feature_methods):

```
def "a feature method with when/then labels"(){
  // setup phase code

  when:
  // stimulus phase code

  then:
  // response phase code

  where:
  // data table
}
```

**Would the below (example 2) edit (of above example, removing just the when/then labels) be still functionally equivalent to above?**

```
def "a feature method withOUT when/then labels"(){
  // setup phase code

  // stimulus phase code

  // response phase code

  where:
  // data table
}
```

I have at least partially convinced myself they are equivalent, with my own before/after testing (of an edit like above) that "appears" to me to function the same (per its results) - but *I am not sure if the respective stimulus/response phases still execute the same, when omitting the labels*.  Despite the identical results from my own testing I mentioned, I'm not sure if there may be differentiating side-effects that may not be so immediately apparent from the results themselves.

I wouldn't be surprised if example 2 above constitutes everything above its `where` block, to be in its [implicit given block](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_given_blocks).  But even if so, I'm not sure if that would make a difference, per the two examples being functionally equivalent or not.

---

Here's a few [when/then block pair](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_when_and_then_blocks) facts (for general context for others):

- If you write one of the {when, then} labels, you *must* write the other - they always exist in [adjacent] pairs.  Can't just write `when:` or just `then:` (for a given pair of stimulus/response phases)
- Multiple when/then block pairs within the same feature method are perfectly fine
- A feature method must always have at least 1 labeled block (per this, I think it doesn't matter which one)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you read the [Spock manual](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M4/all_in_one.html#_blocks). The blocks carry semantics and based on how you structure them the Groovy compiler will apply AST (abstract syntax tree) transformations upon your Spock specifications.

Why would you use Spock and try to cast away the very semantics delivered to you by this tool? If you don't like the behaviour-driven structure of Spock tests, just use pure Java or Groovy tests and the tool of your choice, such as JUnit or TestNG. But then if you wish to use mocks you need additional mock tools which, ironically, often re-introduce a behaviour-driven when-then or given-expect type of structure.

Minimally, as you noticed, you need at least one Spock-specific block in order for the test to be identified as a feature method. While you could omit `given|setup` and just use `expect` instead of `when-then`, this is only applicable to cases in which it makes sense. Try not to force everything into that structure but also use the other block types in order to clearly describe each feature in your specification. Technically, a `then|expect` block brings you the semantic of automatic assertions for all specified conditions (without having to use `assert` or a JUnit method like `assertEquals`). A `where` block brings you easy feature method parametrisation. An optional `cleanup` block helps you to close and/or clean up test resources cleanly without having to manually use `try-finally` constructs.

I suggest you learn how to use Spock as a tool correctly and enjoy its features instead of somehow trying to work around it, which would make using it rather pointless.

Comment: Another point to make: they are not just labels - they can act to "tell a story". It's quite common to write `when: "user is not logged in" ... then: "access to X is denied" ...`

Comment: Yes, but for me that is part of BDD testing style and really just syntactical sugar, even though I heavily use it because a behaviour-driven test is for good reason called a **specification**. That these comments and the labels can be used for test reporting is another advantage. But all of this is documented in the Spock manual.